# Click on a button not working

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver with java.

I have encountered a situation where i am able to locate & click on a button,but nothing happens after this.
The HTML code for the said button is->

```
<div id="divAllButtons" class="UCButtonMainCSS" style="display: none;">
<div>
<div id="OtherActionParent" class="mT8">
<div id="btnSave" class="btn fLt mR20">
<span>
<a onclick="Save_onclick()" href="javascript:void(0)">
<span id="Label24">Save</span>
</a>
</span>
</div>
```

The button when clicked, should redirect to the confirmation page, or show an alert message if mandetory fields are not filled.
I have tried few thing,

**1**

```
Button = driver.findElement(By.id("btnSave"));
Button.click();
```

**2**

```
Button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='dataContainer']/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/a"));
Button.click();
```

**3**

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='dataContainer']/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/a"));
action.moveToElement(we).click().build().perform();
```

**4**

```
Point coordinates = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='dataContainer']/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/a")).getLocation();
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.mouseMove(coordinates.getX()+40,coordinates.getY()+30);
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

Each of the way appears to work fine to click on the button as message **javascript:void(0)** is displayed in the bottom corner of the browser.

Comment: Can you Post your complete code implementation?

Comment: I don't see any button tag though

Comment: @Rupesh What exactly you need

Comment: @Saifur its not necessary that a button must have a **button tag**

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh : Is the button/link visible on the webpage or do you have to perform any actions to make it visible?

Comment: @Subh The button gets visible when atleast one field on the form is filled. I made sure this is done before i click on button,also added few seconds sleep before & after clicking the button

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh: Oh! In that case, if we assume you are entering some data first, before trying to click on the **Save button**, I think the either of the answers given below work. If they don't, please specify, if when manually following the process, does the redirection to the relevant page happens or not ?

Comment: @Subh yes . .!! Manually it all goes smoothly. & as is said in my question,locating element is not the problem.

Comment: What is your exception in that case?

Comment: @Saifur There is no exception,it happens this way. I enter details on the form->I locate element -> I click on the button -> I wait a lot -> execution completes without any exception or error.The thing is that i think **href="javascript:void(0)"** is not working.Any workaround for the same??

Comment: All I can say in that case is try different browser.

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh: If what you are automating, is a public site, can you please give the link, so that I can check at my end ?

Comment: @Saifur Thanks a lot for your time & effort, but i need to get it done on IE only. #Project requirement -(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. **The issue was not to locate the element but the onClick() event was not firing.** Then i found out that something else was there which stopped from the event to fire. I had used java script to enable the date picker box & did this,

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript ("document.getElementById('txtOriginDate').removeAttribute('readonly',0);");

WebElement originDateBox= driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("originDateBox")));
originDateBox.clear();
originDateBox.sendKeys("9-Dec-2014"); //Enter date
```

Developer designed this in such a way that if you don't use date picker to select date, a specific variable was not set. Which eventually made the **onclick** event not to fire.

The date picker code was something like this,

```
var jsoncustdate = "";
var jsonorigindate = "";

function onSelectCalender( StrDt, obj ) 
{
    if ( !varReadonly )
    {
        if ( $( "#txtCustDescisionDate" ).attr( "IsDisable" ) == "FALSE" ) 
        {
            if ( obj.id == "txtCustDescisionDate" ) 
            {
                custobjDt = new Date( obj.selectedYear, obj.selectedMonth,obj.selectedDay, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
                jsoncustdate = custobjDt.getTime();
                jsoncustdate = "\/Date(" + jsoncustdate + ")\/";
                DisabledBtnStage();
        //      $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", objDt);

            }
            if ( obj.id == "txtOriginDate" ) 
            {
                 var objDt = new Date( obj.selectedYear, obj.selectedMonth,obj.selectedDay,0, 0,0,0 );
                 jsonorigindate = objDt.getTime();
                 jsonorigindate = "\/Date(" + jsonorigindate + ")\/";
                 DisabledBtnStage();
        //       $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", objDt);
            }
       }
      elogCommon.CheckMandatory();
   }

}
```

I finally used date picker in normal way & the event fired smoothly.

Thank you guys for help . .cheers !!!

Answer (score 1):

Try a text based xpath search

text based xpath solved a lot of issues for me. You just need to make sure you have enough wait time before clicking the element

**EDIT: try using action**

```
By saveButton = By.xpath("//*[.='Save']");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(saveButton); 
Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
action.moveToElement(element).build().perform(); 
driver.findElement(saveButton).click();
```

*Note: untested code written in java*

Comment: @MasterSlave yes you are right. I assume Shoaib Shaikh already performed additional steps to make the element visible

Comment: The element is already visible,the property @master Slave is concerned about is just a style property **style="display: none;**.also it works fine manually.I even tried to make the button enable explicitly, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to click on the **Save button** and see if it works:

```
WebElement Button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='btnSave]//a"));
Button.click();
```

OR

```
WebElement Button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='btnSave]//span[.='Save']"));
Button.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with javascript executor. it may work....

`WebElement save = driver.findElement(By.id("btnSave"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", save);`